# Allowing Cross - Orgin Requests

Tags: cors

I have been reading about allowing CORS however I have not been able to get it to work for me.

I am linking my site to MusixMatch api to get and show lyrics on my page. I can get it to work locally because I have installed a plugin on chrome to allow the requests. However when this is off and the code is online it still won't work.

I have linked my HTML page that includes D3 JavaScript to a php page which contains this :

```
 <?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 

    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type 
 ?>
```

But it won't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by adding this in front of the URL: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

This got it to work, so the whole url to get data from the api looked like this

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_artist=kanye&q_track=ultralight&apikey=
```

Comment: I believe this solution does not work anymore since the cors-anywhere app service is only available for development purposes.

Comment: Yes, @RodrigoR it's true. It is not working anymore. I tried to add allow cors in the header of the request but it is not working.

Comment: @RodrigoR were you able to find any workaround for this one?

Comment: @TarunDadlani not really. I had to change my project scope to stop using the MusixMatch API

Comment: That's not good. Thanks for the response @RodrigoR